# Confirm navigation not working

Tags: javascript

I have seen this used but it is not working for me

```
 var needToConfirm = true;

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    if (needToConfirm)
        return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
}
```

Comment: The code works fine in our system, did u checked in local

Comment: yes @ChakravarthySM am I missing something?? complete code?

Comment: its working, how else you want it to function

Comment: What could be the reason it is not working on local? @ChakravarthySM

Comment: have you included this inside script tags or calling from separate js file, if so are you calling that file inside your html file

Comment: If still problem persists, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload , you could be using it in a wrong way

Comment: I have included this in script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work in IE and FF with jQuery's:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

});
```